# In what scenario would a .keystore be platform specific?

Tags: java, keystore

Are .keystore files platform specific?

If a keystore is created on Solaris or AIX and a certificate was inserted, can that .keystore file simply be copied to a different platform like Linux or even Windows for use?

If the .keystore file not platform specific is there a scenario in which it could be? For example if one platform used open JDK then moved it to Windows or some other combination of software platform could it make a .keystore file platform specific?

Answer (score 0):

Keystores will work in any platform with java installed, so yes you can switch platforms.